# Laravel 4 Eloquent one-to-many relations error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Using for the first time the Eloquent and i dont understand whats the problem here..

```
class TourItem extends Eloquent {
    public function tour()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Tour');
    }
}

class Tour extends Eloquent {   
    public function tourItem()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('TourItem');
    }
}
```

Here im trying to get the tour itens but only return NULL.

```
    $tour = Tour::where('slug', '=', $postSlug)->where('wrh_id', '=', 1)->first();
    if (!is_null($tour)) {

        var_dump($tour->tourItem);

        foreach ($tour->tourItem as $item) {
            var_dump($item->texto);
        }
    }
```

DB Schema:

```
    Schema::create('tours', function($t) {
                $t->increments('id');
                $t->string('titulo');
                $t->string('slug');
                $t->boolean('main');
                $t->integer('wrh_id');
                $t->timestamps();
            });

    Schema::create('tour_items', function($t) {
                $t->increments('id');
                $t->string('titulo');
                $t->text('texto');
                $t->text('saiba_mais');
                $t->integer('tour_id');
                $t->timestamps();
            });
```

Where is the error??

Thank you 
Roberto

Comment: What is your DB schema?

Comment: Just add the DB Schema!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

I test your migrations and model, and all works without touching anything. I create a repo at [github](https://github.com/rodrigore/l4-stack-question) replying your question.

I'm not sure why didn't work for Roberto, but maybe you are doing some mistake in setting your database or migration.

I hope that the code from repository help you, and make sure to follow the instruction of the Readme.

Comment: http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations says it is possible to access it as a property.

Comment: That's why i did this. But now using as function, the $tour->tourItem() is not null but when using in the foreach they dont work.. suggestions??? Maybe some name convention error in database??

Comment: I've the same problem. I created an issue for this on the Github page: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1362

Comment: You tested the repository that I made for you?

Comment: Hi Rodri, thank you very much! Well... copy and paste your code in my.. the only diference between ours is the name of the seeder class... You are using TourItemTableSeeder and i was using TourItensTableSeeder ... And it works... Now i dont now why this is happening... but.. anyway.. thank you very much ;)